# What do I need to install nopCommerce?

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008

Extremely sorry for this question, but what do I need to install on my local windows 7 PC.

http://www.nopcommerce.com/default.aspx

Would I need IIS7 or Windows Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look here: http://www.nopcommerce.com/technologysystemrequirements.aspx

It says:

Supported web servers:
    Internet Information Service (IIS) 5.1 or above